# Do you like Taekwondo?

Tags: code-golf, string

[Choi Hong Hi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choi_Hong_Hi) died on the 15th June 2002 at the honorable age of 83. He founded [Taekwondo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taekwondo).

15 years after his death, I would like to be a Taekwondo master. This is my time to shine !

## Task

Given a string you should output a *Taekwondo* version.

## Rules

- You will receive a non-empty string/sentence by any valid input
- You must replace each titles (case insensitive)  by the [revised romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_Romanization_of_Korean) equivalent.
- You must add `, *side kick*` at the end of the sentence because I like to do side kicks.
- You must output this changed sentence as a string.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) you should aim to minimize the byte count of your answer

## Examples

```
"I am a Student and I do Taekwondo twice a week" 
  => "I am a Geup and I do Taekwondo twice a week, *side kick*"

"I am a Teacher willing to be a President" 
  => "I am a Gyosa nim willing to be a Gwanjang nim, *side kick*"
```

## List of titles

```
English             =>  Revised Romanization
============================================
President           =>  Gwanjang nim
Founder             =>  Gwanjang nim
Master instructor   =>  Sabeom nim
Teacher             =>  Gyosa nim
Black Belt          =>  Dan
Student             =>  Geup
Color Belt          =>  Geup
Master level        =>  Godanja
```

Comment: case insensitive? and is a space needed before `*side kick*`

Comment: @LiefdeWen Yes `Teacher == teacher == tEaCher`

Comment: @LiefdeWen The space is obviously needed. How can you do a `side kick` without space between you and your opponent ?

Comment: As a Korean guy, I approve of this challenge. But I must say that `Geup` (급) doesn't really mean 'student.' `Haksaeng` (학생) would be better. Also, you would use `Sabeom nim` (사범님) instead of `Gyosa nim` (교사님) when it comes to martial arts instructor, regardless of the mastery (The word `Gyobeom nim` (교범님) exists, but it's rarely used).

Comment: Will you make changes as a consequence of JungHwanMin's comment? (to be sure I won't post an answer that will become invalid afterwards)

Comment: I'm guessing that those labels came from the Wikipedia page, but they're wrong nonetheless.

Comment: Any chance the input to end in punctuation? “I'm strong!” → “I'm strong! \*side kick\*” (no comma after punctuation) or “I'm strong!” → “I'm strong, \*side kick\*!” (insert before punctuation) would add a little twist.

Comment: `side kick` is different of `side-kick`

Comment: Are the titles guaranteed to be whole words? I mean, should “I run in presidential election” become “I run in Gwanjang nimial election, \*side kick\*”?

Comment: Dan is a blackbelt in Taekwondo is always true.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Thanks for the comment. I only took the translation from wikipedia

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder It won't change

Comment: @sergiol Question updated

Comment: @manatwork The end of the sentence is not important. Just add `, *side kick*`

Comment: @manatwork Yes the title should be the full word

Comment: Can we assume that the input will always contain a title to translate?

Comment: @Titus Yes always a title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 154 bytes

```
i(`president|founder
Gwanjang_
master instructor
Sabeom_
teacher
Gyosa_
black belt
Dan
student|color belt
Geup
master level
Godanja
_
 nim
$
, *side kick*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BboMwEEX3cwovqihCvURLGlqJQgRkTQczTVyMB9kmVaXendpEUbp78/X151nyyuCyqO3HZMmpnoz//eTZ9GQh@0bzhebUwojOkxXKOG9n6dlCjR3x2IInlOfY/WGHLXQa5SA60h52aMD5eV2UrNle44zm6ban6UIaMu7jH2hBGDXCAzyKJJqIQckhWZbDTUxsxPSP9@Wx2L1UgcanugnwVtRNdUyb0oYsiKWvFOnuFI56NWoCpZxzJZ4pj/H7VSiPQn8)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 241 bytes

```php
<?=preg_replace(["#\b(President|Founder)\b#i","#\bMaster instructor\b#i","#\bTeacher\b#i","#\bBlack Belt\b#i","#\b(Studen|Color Bel)t\b#i","#\bMaster level\b#i"],[Gwanjang.$n=" nim",Sabeom.$n,Gyosa.$n,Dan,Geup,Godanja],"$argn, *side-kick*");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDNboMwEITvPIXl5ACR0xegaaSkKeLQHynckihaYAUuYFuLKaoU9a17pnZ6SKXedmdWn2bW1Ga6X5vaBEik6UxoNFmpqvBrd355zdLtLoqDOVClVjxl0DFgezuUqCwDVbKUlZplgM2olZvsKAt0JyNiw@Ng/eDgK0NYeXALBYYHPjvm4RthLz3k8qQHVSJFx3wmufDmM/QWiUnVWxoKq@lmZQhFjX@EjWM2bIOtvWnhb77LVreavBfZf/AWP7C9qidxSEZQ76Cqu7nryJTsuNhDjrpzgkg@dQ9@eAS34GBEokt/fxL8@hbBFr7KspFFs@BRPE3fSi8LH/QH)

Comment: As I count, it would be shorter with `str_ireplace()`.

Comment: Unclear what “You must output this changed sentence as a string.” actually means, but given the side kick must always be added, I would say the sentence will always change, so something should always be output. For example in case of input like “Me coder, no Taekwondo”.

Comment: @manatwork It is say valid input. Under valid input I assume a input with a title. Your count with `str_ireplace` was right

Comment: There seems to be enough “ nim” to worth a variable: `[$a=Gwanjang.$n=" nim",$a,Sabeom.$n,Gyosa.$n,…`.

Comment: @manatwork Yes it saves two bytes. I have tried a version with additional `strtr` but it saves nothing

Comment: Fails for "presidential" ... that should _not_ be translated. Add a couple of `\b`s to all your regexes, drop the `str_ireplace` approach. And: won´t `preg_filter` fail if there is nothing to translate?

Comment: @Titus I know! Are your examples valid inputs? In this case I would change my approachs. And then we must handle special characters for the regex we must add a preg_quote

Comment: Read the comments on the question: `the title should be the full word`. I don´t see any special char in the given titles; so no need for escaping. Apart from these issues: there´s probably no shorter approach than those 238 bytes.

Comment: @Titus fixed 238?

Comment: Oh right ... I forgot the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 262 bytes

```c#
s=>{for(int i=0;i<8;)s=s.ToUpper().Replace("PRESIDENT|FOUNDER|MASTER INSTRUCTOR|TEACHER|BLACK BELT|MASTER LEVEL|STUDENT|COLOR BELT".Split('|')[i],(i<2?"GWANJANG":i>3?"GEUP":"SABEOM|GYOSA|DAN|GODANJA".Split('|')[i-2])+(i++<4?" NIM":""));return s+", *SIDE KICK*";}
```

Full/Formatted version:

```c#
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Func<string, string> f = s =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8;)
                s = s.ToUpper().Replace("PRESIDENT|FOUNDER|MASTER INSTRUCTOR|TEACHER|BLACK BELT|MASTER LEVEL|STUDENT|COLOR BELT".Split('|')[i],
                                        (i < 2 ? "GWANJANG"
                                               : i > 3 ? "GEUP"
                                                       : "SABEOM|GYOSA|DAN|GODANJA".Split('|')[i-2])
                                        + (i++ < 4 ? " NIM" : ""));

            return s + ", *SIDE KICK*";
        };

        System.Console.WriteLine(f("I am a Student and I do Taekwondo twice a week"));
        System.Console.WriteLine(f("I am a Teacher willing to be a President"));

        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: We should ask if `*SIDE KICK*` can be in this form, in the examples it was lowercased

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder The comment on the OP says it is case-insensitive, either way it isn't a change in byte count. Also a kick in upper case is more powerful so it should be allowed...

Comment: Yes, just making that remark... This answer is Lethal anyways :))

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 163 bytes

```
i`President|Founder
Gwanjang¶
i`Master instructor
Sabeom¶
i`Teacher
Gyosa¶
i`Black Belt
Dan
i`Student|Color Belt
Geup
i`Master level
Godanja
¶
 nim
$
, *side kick*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9NCsJADIX3c4osXBVPUcXiQhDqAZq2ocZOMzKTsQieywN4sbE/oNvvke@9eFIWTImrs6fALYm@Di5KS94UI8oNpfu8DVcnDEoeWIL62KjzpsSa3LCEF8LmOl88XcCF5BabHnKyavYoEyg1LvKds86vQUHx/jdbepA1hWvnUjNJQHgwG7OFbN4FPTd9ltIRcAAEXRthZGtZOlAHNU3898UX)

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 212

```
puts "[string map -nocase {President Gwanjang\ nim Founder Gwanjang\ nim Master\ instructor Sabeom\ nim Teacher Gyosa\ nim Black\ Belt Dan Student Geup Color\ Belt Geup Master\ level Godanja} $argv], *side kick*"
```

### [demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNWw0Uk9uV1JpZkk)

Comment: @manatwork: fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 281 bytes

```python
import re
x=input();a="Gwanjang";b=" nim";c="Geup";d="Master";e=" Belt"
for i in range(8):x=re.sub("(?i)"+["President","Founder",d+" instructor","Teacher","Black"+e,"Student","Color"+e,d+" level"][i],[a+b,a+b,"Sabeom"+b,"Gyosa"+b,"Dan",c,c,"Godanja"][i],x)
print(x+", *side kick*")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9BT8MwDIXv/RXWO7Vr4MIFUVWTBmLigIQ0btUOaWq2sDSp0pR1P5xzSWBCliX72Z/lN1zC0dm7ZdH94Hwgz9lcaztMIS8qWWN7lvZT2gOqtgZZ3aNSUeVpQNXVeJVjYI@K43DDJiD7cJ40aUs@UpzfFw9z7fl2nNoc@VoXKBu8eR51xzZA4NlNtosnRFciYmPwkwou9nhnqY5pgo2R6oSSBXZhunKPzsStqCXO8Bcb7Bu9F40sW5ESO9my65HK7cWN8rd6khZCxcDWdcnaHzUX2eC1DflcQtAqfUcnrU4rFMvyQrInSdd/6KyN0fZAwVHLUf93823djUo7Pw)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 251 bytes

```
a=>a.replace(RegExp(b='president|founder|master instructor|teacher|black belt|student|color belt|master level','gi'),c=>((d='Gwanjang nim|')+d+'Sabeom nim|Gyosa nim|Dan|Geup|Geup|Godanja').split`|`[b.split`|`.indexOf(c.toLowerCase())])+', *side kick*'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDNTsMwEITvfQrfbLclb5BeAEWVkEC0N4TUjb0JbhxvZDtNkfzuwf2BG5fVaOxvtTNHOEFQ3gzxwZHGeW7KBZQbKDwOFhSKd2yfz4OoSz54DEaji6mh0Wn0qYcQ0TPjQvSjiuRTRFBf@aXObMdqtDGFOF4hRZb8zbpzFk9o@Zq3hsu1KjdC6JJXE7gjuJY50ycuV3rFd1Aj9Vej@qYAV/UELlU4DvdB@oJxWYTBmnhIh4/6TxYmX3t@bYQqIr3QhP4RAgopP@WKr9nykop1RnVLvlgocoEsFpZa0Qi@ZdAzYLtbCAZOsy3TxPaA3UQuqzgZhfnLhNhxKf9ZsL8VwyZjrcnpIuUqsv/2W2pG5/kH)

This is not as compact as it could be since JavaScript is so verbose, but it's a great question. I recognized most of these terms as I am a 2nd Dan Black Belt in Taekwondo.

**Explanaion**

```
a=>
  a.replace(                                    // Replace on input string
    RegExp(                                     // Regex matching English phrases
      b='president|founder|master instructor|teacher|black belt|student|color belt|master level',
      'gi'                                      // Match all, case insensitive
    ),
    c=>
      ((d='Gwanjang nim|')+d+                   // Duplicate string portion
        'Sabeom nim|Gyosa nim|Dan|Geup|Geup|Godanja') // Add remaining phrases
      .split`|`                                 // Split into array by pipe
        [b.split`|`.indexOf(c.toLowerCase())])  // Access Korean phrase by corresponding index of matched English phrase
      +', *side kick*'                          // I like to do side kicks
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 233 bytes

```
s=>(btoa`>·¬×§·mÁ©ãjx4)µ§uêö§©àÒx¦ÔÆ¬µêô{-®ç-¢½i·¨IâTÞiÈ^¯a²¢Æ´)µV@^Ýj}R¶ç^Ýzêu
h¯@^Ýzêu1«-z½%z÷¥ØjjxÚ`.split(0).join` `.split`1`.map(d=>([a,b]=d.split(/2+/),s=s.replace(RegExp(a,'gi'),b))),s+', *side kick*"')
```

```js
f=
s=>(btoa`>·¬×§·mÁ©ãjx4)µ§uêö§©àÒx¦ÔÆ¬µêô{-®ç-¢½i·¨IâTÞiÈ^¯a²¢Æ´)µV@^Ýj}R¶ç^Ýzêu
h¯@^Ýzêu1«-z½%z÷¥ØjjxÚ`.split(0).join` `.split`1`.map(d=>([a,b]=d.split(/2+/),s=s.replace(RegExp(a,'gi'),b))),s+', *side kick*"')

console.log(f('I am a Teacher willing to be a President'))
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 243 bytes

```
s=>(`President${A=':Gwanjang nim|'}Founder${A}Master instructor:Sabeom nim|Teacher:Gyosa nim|Black Belt:Dan|Student:Geup|Color Belt:Geup|Master level:Godanja`.split`|`.map(r=>([a,b]=r.split`:`,s=s.replace(RegExp(a,'gi'),b))),s+', *side kick*')
```

```js
f=
s=>(`President${A=':Gwanjang nim|'}Founder${A}Master instructor:Sabeom nim|Teacher:Gyosa nim|Black Belt:Dan|Student:Geup|Color Belt:Geup|Master level:Godanja`.split`|`.map(r=>([a,b]=r.split`:`,s=s.replace(RegExp(a,'gi'),b))),s+', *side kick*')

console.log(f('I am a Teacher willing to be a President'))
```